# PHP How can i include a var in my mail message?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, var

Good Day,

I have a form that saves Name, Email, Subject, Tel Number, Message, and a checkbox.

I m sadly not so good in php at all. Im just started to learn the basics. Thats why i need a little help from you :)

The Form

```
<form class="contact-form" id="contact" role="form">

                <!-- IF MAIL SENT SUCCESSFULLY -->
                <h6 class="success">
                <span class="olored-text icon_check"></span> Your Message has been send. </h6>

                <!-- IF MAIL SENDING UNSUCCESSFULL -->
                <h6 class="error">
                <span class="colored-text icon_error-circle_alt"></span> Error  </h6>

                <div class="field-wrapper col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control input-box" id="cf-name" type="text" name="cf-name" placeholder="Name*" required>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrapper col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control input-box" id="cf-email" type="email" name="cf-email" placeholder="E-Mail*" required>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrapper col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control input-box" id="cf-subject" type="text" name="cf-subject" placeholder="Subject*" required>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrapper col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control input-box" id="cf-number" type="tel" name="cf-number" placeholder="Number">
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrapper col-md-12">
                    <textarea class="form-control textarea-box" id="cf-message" rows="7" name="cf-message" placeholder="Message*" required></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-check col-md-12">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Checkdata" required>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="Checkdata"> yes to this*</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 ">
                    <p>*required</p>
                </div>

                <button class="btn standard-button" type="submit" id="cf-submit" name="submit" data-style="expand-left">Send</button>
            </form>
```

Now i need this information: Name, Subject, Email, Number and if the checkbox was checked. I would like to include the Number and the checkbox info in the message, that will send as a email to me, because the Name, Subject and Email info will go in the email header.

I figured out how i could save all to the header, but im not really sure about how to include something in the message. Do i have to sent a HTML email for that? or can i do it without html?

There goes my php code

```
        <?php

if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {


  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


  mail( "hey@example.net", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], $headers );


}
?>
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but assuming you want to append more text to the message?

You can do something like this:

```
$more_message = $_POST['name']. "hello, this is more \n";

  mail( "hey@example.net", $_POST['subject'], $more_message.$_POST['message'], $headers );
```

---

Update based on comment below on additional requirements:

```
$header_1 = $_POST['subject'] ."\n" .$_POST['name'] ."\n";
$more_message = $_POST['message']. "\n". $_POST['number'] ."\n". $_POST['Checkdata'];
```

something like this...

Comment: This email goes to me when a user send a message via this form. I want that the email looks like this: Header with subject name email.. then Message: with the message from the user and if he put his number in the form his number and if he checked the checkbox. Like Message: Message + Number + is checkedbox checked? = true/false. But big thank you anyway.

Comment: see above edited. YOU can expand on above to get the exact format of your email.